# Oracle + Oci8 + php5.6 + ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, oracle, ubuntu

Tengo instalado ubuntu 16.04 , con `PHP5.6`.
Me descargué una versión de Oracle instantclient(sdk y basics) `Oracle 12.1.0.1.0`, la descomprimí sobre `/opt/oracle/instantclient.`Luego exporté la variable como la home de oracle `Export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient`
Cree un par de enlaces a las librerías.

```
$ sudo ln -s libocci.so.12.1 libocci.so
$ sudo ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so
```

Añadí al sistema la variable:

```
$echo /opt/oracle/instantclient > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient
```

Posteriormente creé la carpeta `/opt/oracle/instantclient/src` y descomprimí la versión del oci     `oci8-2.0.10.tgz` descomprimiendolo con `$sudo tar xzvf`. 
Ejecuté  `$phpize` con el siguiente resultado:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
```

Ejecuté con posterioridad:

```
$./configure -with-oci8=share,instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient
```

Resutaldo:

```
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib/php/20151012
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php/20151012
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... nawk
checking if nawk is broken... no
checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 7.0.7, ok
checking OCI8 DTrace support... no
checking size of long int... 8
checking checking if we're on a 64-bit platform... yes
checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /opt/oracle/instantclient
checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... /opt/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include
checking Oracle Instant Client library version compatibility... 12.1
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) nawk
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

Parece que todo está bien pero cuando ejecuto `$make` me da el siguiente error:

```
/bin/bash /opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10/include -I/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10/main -I/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10 -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10/oci8.c -o oci8.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10/include -I/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10/main -I/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10 -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/opt/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
/opt/oracle/src/oci8-2.0.10/oci8.c:36:40: fatal error: ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:196: recipe for target 'oci8.lo' failed
make: *** [oci8.lo] Error 1
```

Alguna idea de que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Muchas gracias @LuiggiMendoza, editaré la entrada. Un saludo.

Comment: Tengo entendido que es un problema de versiones, quizás esto pueda ayudarte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145605/pecl-oci8-failed-install-after-upgrade-to-php5-6

Comment: He intentado también esa solución pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: @AlexisC.C. tienes instalados los siguientes paquetes de Ubuntu? `php-pear php5-dev build-essential libaio1` (tomado de [aquí](https://kogentadono.com/2011/11/02/installing-oci8-on-ubuntu/) )

Comment: @AlexisC.C. sólo por completitud de tu pregunta, podrías indicar en ella de dónde has tomado los pasos de instalción (así nadie te referencia a ellos).

Comment: @AlexisC.C. puede verse en los logs que enviaste que está instalado PHP7 `checking PHP version... 7.0.7, ok` (PHP API 20151012 se correspondería con ello también). Ahora bien,  en PHP7, al parecer han cambiado `php_smart_str` a `php_smart_string` de acuerdo a los comentarios con este [link](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/682). Sugiero que instales la versión deseada de PHP, es decir 5.6 y vuelvas a probar.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el mismo problemo, porque tenia 2 instalaciones de php, y la principal era php7 que no es compatible con este version.

Para verificar la version usada : `cat /usr/bin/php-config` o `php -v`

Para cambiar la version :

Desde : https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar5.6 
sudo update-alternatives --set phpize /usr/bin/phpize5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set php-config /usr/bin/php-config5.6
```

Y ahora cuando hago desde el principio, functionna :

```
cd /tmp/oci8-2.0.8
phpize
./configure --with-oci8=share,instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/lib
make
sudo make install
```

La procedura completa era : http://blog.henriet.eu/installation-extension-oci8-pour-php-sous-linux.html

*disculpa mi espanol*

Answer (score 1):

Parece un problema de versiones incompatibles. Debes asegurarte de que las versiones de `phpize`, y la de PHP de destino de la instalacion del modulo sean la misma.

Para ello existe la opcion `--with-php-config` [(ver aqui)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/install.pecl.phpize.php#82914). Por ejemplo:

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config5.6 --with-oci8=...
```